# Wordpress PHP Version is Different from server

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I have a WP website that run on ubuntu 14.4 with php 7.0.21.
but when i check the WP PHP version i get `Running PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22`
on the server `php -v` comment return :

`PHP 7.0.21-1~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  6 2017 09:38:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.21-1~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies`

Why do I have this conflict?
Do I need to make any upgrade in WP?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: This is possibly due to an entry in your **.htaccess** file. See possible solutions here: [link]http://www.beyondmyfrontdoor.com/wp/how-to-fix-wordpress-reporting-the-wrong-php-version/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the version that was defined on Apache was different from that configured on the server.
I Fixed that by change the defulte php version on the apache

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo services apache2 restart
```